# Android error: cannot login with email and password

Tags: android

hello everyone I have this problem in my app.
in my login view:

```
    <com.example.ciyashop.customview.edittext.EditTextRegular
                    android:id="@+id/etEmail"
                    style="@style/txt_gray_medium"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/value_8"
                    android:hint="@string/email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/value_8"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                    android:textDirection="locale"
                    android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Base"
                    app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/ic_user" />

<com.example.ciyashop.customview.edittext.EditTextRegular
                    android:id="@+id/etPass"
                    style="@style/txt_gray_medium"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/value_8"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/value_8"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                    android:textDirection="locale"
                    android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Base"
                    app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/ic_password" />
```

these are the email and password fields.
I get this error:
unexpected resource type 'drawable' expected: string.

Comment: Which line of code does the error refer to?

Comment: app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/ic_password"

Comment: every app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable ....

Comment: in my application have the same error

Comment: I delete this line and when i try to log in i have this error E/Exception is: Invalid Api key

Comment: Please write code also so that one can understand where the problem occurs.

Comment: can you tell me what code do you need I am new with android